# Firebase/database import error in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to import firebase/database to use the realtime database in firebase with my react native application. But while importing it's showing me this error

> Unable to resolve module firebase/database from /Users/yadukrishnan.u/Documents/Academics/App Development/Youtube tutorials/Firebase CRUD/firebase-crud/App.js: firebase/database could not be found within the project or in these directories:
> node_modules
> ../../../../../../node_modules

import code:

```
import {getDatabase} from 'firebase/database';
import { ref, set } from 'firebase/database';
```

I have installed Firebase version: '9.8.1'

Package.json

```
  "name": "firebase-crud",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "firebase": "^9.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: UPDATE: It's working fine when I am running on web. But it's showing the above error when I try to run on IOS or android simulator

Comment: Did you use `npm i firebase` to install firebase?

Comment: If so, you should instead be using a plugin

Comment: Yes I used npm install firebase command

Comment: So you should use a react native plugin instead

Comment: Check https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

Comment: Like React native firebase plugin ?

Comment: Yeah, you should use a react native plugin